# How to use a command line javascript program in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, command-line

I'm new to javascript and I'm exploring a javascript program that is designed to run in command line. It expects some arguments to run, for example:

```
> thescript --option1 argument1  --option2 argument 2.. etc
```

How can I use this script in a webpage? This is, reference it within the HTML and be able to pass the arguments needed to the script (like can be done in terminal) and get the output in a variable. Hope make sense. Thanks

Comment: `How can I use this script in a webpage?` you can't

Comment: Browsers are explicitly designed not to allow access to the command line, you can't

Comment: @JaromandaX; @Tibrogargan Ok, so the only way is to modify the code changing the "console.log()" to "return something"?

Comment: no, you'll probably want to look into how web clients "communicate" with server side code ... i.e. the term AJAX is a good starting point

Comment: @JaromandaX, Ok, I'll check that. One last question. The same program has command line versions in java and c++. Would be the same difficulty converting for example the java code in order to run in webpage?

Comment: web pages can't "run" server side code regardless what language the server side code is written in

Comment: The usual Web Page architecture has a number of steps.  1) a server reads web page source from a file system.  2) Optionally, the server executes some code that modifies the code ("server side web components"), 3) The web page is transmitted to the browser and 4) the browser renders the page.  JavaScript components that are server side can run code on the operating system (i.e. Node.js), but because browsers are "sandboxes", nothing that directly touches hardware is allowed to run in the browser ("client side components" or "presentation layer components").

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you're trying to do is send a command through your terminal to a client side page?

unfortunately it wouldn't work that way.

if what you're trying to do is add command line arguments in your nodeJS application to then send to your client within the code you can do something like:

```
const args = process.argv.slice(2); // Exclude the first two default arguments

// Parse command-line arguments
const options = {};
for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2) {
  const argName = args[i];
  const argValue = args[i + 1];
  if (argName.startsWith('--')) {
    options[argName.slice(2)] = argValue;
  }
}

// Access the value of the --dogs argument
const dogs = options['dogs'];

console.log(dogs);
```

then just run node server.js --dogs "good fluffy boiiiiiii!!!"

hopefully that answers your question. once you have that code you could run express and do something like:

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(dogs);

});
```

that will send the value of dogs to your client side, you would just have to run the command I mentioned before. Hopefully that helps you out a bit, have a good day!!! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not sure if I'm doing a NodeJS app. Actually what I've seen is that have scripts written in javascript within the HMTL is more straight forward than having the script in another language like python, ruby, etc. Then, I´d like to use this javascript code within a page, but unfortunately, I only have this command line version. If I have good javscript level probably I'd modify the script to be able to use it directly in webpage.

Comment: I see, can you edit your question with the code you want it to execute? I'm sure we can get a working snippet of code started for what you're trying to do! :) :) :)

Comment: basically is the javascript version of [this](https://qqwing.com/download.html) site that says how to run it in nodejs. Thanks for the help